# Call Oracle Stored Procedure and Package with Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application, and I am using Enterprise Library to connect to my Oracle database.

I always used SQL Server before, and this is the way I used to call it.

```
Database db = readConfig.ReadWebConfig();
SP_NAME = "Get_Data";

using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_NAME))
{
    //Pass parameters
    dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "CommParent_ID", DbType.Int32, comment.CommParent_id);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Type_ID", DbType.Int32, comment.Type_id);

    IRowMapper<CommentEntity> resmapper = MapBuilder<CommentEntity>.MapAllProperties()
                                                  .Map(x => x.UserEmail).ToColumn("Email")
                                                  .Map(x => x.Nick).ToColumn("FullName")
                                                  .Map(x => x.User_id).ToColumn("User_ID")
                                                  .Map(x => x.Comment_id).ToColumn("Comment_ID")
                                                  .Build();

    List<CommentEntity> result = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<CommentEntity>(SP_NAME, resmapper, dbCommand.Parameters).ToList<CommentEntity>();
}
```

The problem I have using Oracle is that the stored procedure is embedded in a package and package body.

My question is, how I set package name in my call.

Thanks

Comment: did you try: SP_NAME = "package_name.Get_Data"; ?

Comment: Thanks... One more question.. how I define a AddOutParameter for cursor type?.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your stored procedure name to:

```
SP_NAME = "package_name.Get_Data";
```

To add a SYS_REFCURSOR out parameter use this:

```
OracleParameter oraP = new OracleParameter();
oraP.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
oraP.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(oraP);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a new error that i am posting in another post.